Are there commands in PowerShell 7 to split the current window into four and request to run Python files in each of them?
Currently, I click + 3x while holding Alt to create four divided terminals within the same tab:  

In each of these, I need to run a different Python commnd:


cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test One" && python one.py



cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Two" && python two.py



cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Three" && python three.py



cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Four" && python four.py




Currently, I paste these paths manually, pressing Enter:  

Is there any way to achieve this same result but in an automated way?

I'm not referring to mouse autoclick and things like that, I'm referring to commands in PowerShell itself, or something like that, to achieve this result


+1 on this question. I didn't know you could do that, and its actually really useful to hold alt while click on + to get it inline.

cd could be made more efficient with environment variables, e.g.: cd "${env:UserProfile}\Desktop\Test <#>". Does python not support environment variables, such as python "${env:UserProfile}\Desktop\Test One\one.py"?

@JW0914 they're using batch, in which case it is %USERPROFILE%\Desktop\Test

@LPChip PowerShell - please see title and screenshots. Double ampersands [&&] are processed in PowerShell, whereas singles [&] are replaced with ;

@JW0914 ah. I tried && in my powershell and that didn't work, but ; did. nevermind then. :)

Adding to the other answer, wt can use -d to specify a target directory
The commands below can be saved as a .bat or .ps1 script, and can be run directly from cmd or powershell (except the commented lines):
# start in first (top left) window
wt /w 0    -d "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test One"   powershell.exe -noexit -C python one.py
# top right
wt /w 0 sp -d "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Two"   powershell.exe -noexit -C python two.py
# bottom left
wt /w 0 fp /t 0
wt /w 0 sp -d "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Three" powershell.exe -noexit -C python three.py
# bottom right
wt /w 0 fp /t 1
wt /w 0 sp -d "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Four"  powershell.exe -noexit -C python four.py

This starts powershell (the shell you started in your screenshot) in the specified folder, then launches your python script from there.
You can remove powershell.exe -noexit -C to start python directly, but be aware that when the python script ends, that terminal window will exit entirely instead of going back to a shell prompt.

You can call windows terminal [wt] with the split-pane [sp] function to create a new window in split pane, and you can specify /w 0 to do so in the current window; essentially you can run this myscript.cmd:
wt /w 0 sp
cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test One" && python one.py

wt /w 0 sp
cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Two" && python two.py

wt /w 0 sp
cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Three" && python three.py

:: -- Switch back to the first pane, so we get a nice 4 squared window.
wt /w 0 fp /t 0

wt /w 0 sp
cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test Four" && python four.py


For more info and to get a list of all options, including switching between panes and windows and stuff: wt /?

If it doesn't work correctly, you can put the command on one line too, e.g. creating a new tab to run ping within, returning focus back to the first tab while ping runs:
# cmd:
  wt /w 0 sp paping 8.8.8.8 -p 443 && wt /w 0 fp /t 0

# powershell:
  wt /w 0 sp paping 8.8.8.8 -p 443;wt /w 0 fp /t 0

EDIT: Based on this question, I've created the following function and stored it in my profile:
function RunSplit {
    param (
        [string]$program
    )
    $command = "wt /w 0 sp $program;wt /w 0 fp /t 0"
    Invoke-Expression $command
}

I can now type RunSplit "ping google.com" to ping google in a separate tab.


Hello @LPChip, thank you in advance for your time and attention, I put a check mark in the answer but I did some additional tests by putting a sleep(5) in the Python codes to look slowly at the execution, I noticed that all 4 files are being executed in the same split (first/main) instead of each code being executed in one of 4 different parts, could you help me solve this issue, please?

I tried to adjust according to your additional instructions but I was unsuccessful.

Remove the enters, and put each row on its own line, that should do it.

I tried to do this but it generating new tabs instead of splitting the actual tab.

Try it like this: wt /w 0 sp cd "C:\Users\Computador\Desktop\Test One";python one.py;wt /w 0 fp /t 0

error 2147942402 (0x80070002) when starting [the file folder is written in front] and it also starts opening several new different tabs with the same error code
